# how to escape special character colon (':') in jsonpath

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, jsonpath, jsonparser

**Json:**

```
{
    "im:rating": {
        "label": "1"
    }
}
```

While trying to use Jsonpath in groovy 
If i am using this **'$.im:rating'**

It is showing following error

> ```
> Caused by: com.nebhale.jsonpath.InvalidJsonPathExpressionException: Illegal
> ```
>
> character 'PathCharacter [types=[], value=:, position=4]'
>       $.im:rating
>       ----^
>       Illegal character 'PathCharacter [types=[SIMPLE_NAME_CHARACTER, LETTER, COMPLEX_NAME_CHARACTER], value=r, position=5]'
>       $.im:rating
>       -----^
>       Illegal character 'PathCharacter [types=[SIMPLE_NAME_CHARACTER, LETTER, COMPLEX_NAME_CHARACTER], value=a, position=6]'
>       $.im:rating
>       ------^
>       Illegal character 'PathCharacter [types=[SIMPLE_NAME_CHARACTER, LETTER, COMPLEX_NAME_CHARACTER], value=t, position=7]'
>       $.im:rating
>       -------^
>       Illegal character 'PathCharacter [types=[SIMPLE_NAME_CHARACTER, LETTER, COMPLEX_NAME_CHARACTER], value=i, position=8]'
>       $.im:rating
>       --------^
>       Illegal character 'PathCharacter [types=[SIMPLE_NAME_CHARACTER, LETTER, COMPLEX_NAME_CHARACTER], value=n, position=9]'
>       $.im:rating
>       ---------^
>       Illegal character 'PathCharacter [types=[SIMPLE_NAME_CHARACTER, LETTER, COMPLEX_NAME_CHARACTER], value=g, position=10]'
>       $.im:rating
>       ----------^
>
> ```
>   at com.nebhale.jsonpath.JsonPath.compile(JsonPath.java:85)
>   at com.nebhale.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:182)
> ```

Comment: Hi kaushik, Did you solve this problem? How did you escape the ":" with nebhale json parser library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can access alternatively with the following

**'$..label'**

Answer (score 6):

`$['im:rating']`

> Selects the specified property in a parent object. Be sure to put single quotes around the property name.
> Tip: Use this notation if the property name contains special characters such as spaces, or begins with a character other than A..Za..z_.
> https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using the JsonPath library at:

https://github.com/nebhale/JsonPath

In general it is bad form on stack overflow to not post a proper code example and not refer to the exact library (including version) you are using. Without this information the community is left guessing and doing research on your part.

With that said, my take would be that this is a limitation of that specific JsonPath library and as far as I understand it, it is in this specific case not adhering to the json specification.

The following code:

```
@Grab('com.nebhale.jsonpath:jsonpath:1.2')
import com.nebhale.jsonpath.*

def path = JsonPath.compile('$.im:rating')
```

when run, results in the error you are describing.

If we instead try using the built-in groovy `JsonSlurper`:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = '''\
{
    "im:rating": {
        "label": "1"
    }
}'''

def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
println "value: ${parsed['im:rating']}"
```

we get:

```
~> groovy use_slurper_instead.groovy
value: [label:1]
```

i.e. there are no problems using keys with `:` characters in them. I would raise an issue with JsonPath.